# Safari iframe visibility hidden not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I have an iframe and it's code is:

`<iframe page_id="3" allowtransparency="true" src="https://www.mysite.com/" name="custom-frame" id="custom-frame-2044963" class="custom-frame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 1014px; width: 1060px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="0" content_height="217"></iframe>`

For some reason `visibility: hidden` is not working in Safari yet it is in Chrome and FF. I've never come across this before. It seems to be a new issue since this code is very very old. Any ideas?

I am not toggling `display` to avoid some other issues.

**EDIT** It looks like a Safari bug? http://jsfiddle.net/y2V3T/ v7.0.4

Comment: I removed all the attributes aside from `style` and still no good

Comment: Can you demonstrate in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @jfriend00 just made one and posted it as you commented :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to hide youtube iframes in safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503598/unable-to-hide-youtube-iframes-in-safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this is a legit bug, as I think it is:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134774

Answer (score 3):

If visibility: hidden is not working you can also use opacity: 0;

The code would look like this:

```
<iframe page_id="3" allowtransparency="true" src="https://www.example.com/" name="custom-frame" id="custom-frame-2044963" class="custom-frame" style="opacity: 0; height: 1014px; width: 1060px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="0" content_height="217"></iframe>
```