# jquery opacity not working with safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, jquery-animate

The code line `$('#iframe-youtube').css("opacity", "0");` below works on every browser except Safari. The rest of the code works at every browser include Safari. By the way I have also tried `$('#iframe-youtube').animate({opacity: '0'},0)` but it didnt work neither.

```
$('#bg').fadeOut(500);
$('#hand-iphone').animate({opacity: '0', bottom: '-5px'},0);
$('#hand2-iphone').animate({opacity: '0'},0);
$('#iframe-youtube').css("opacity", "0");
$('#hand-iphone2').show().animate({opacity: '0', bottom: '-5px' , left: '95px'},0);
$('#hand2-iphone2').show().animate({opacity: '0'},0);
$('.roundabout-holder').show().animate({opacity: '0'},0);
$('#boni-text').show().animate({opacity: '0'},0);           
$('#hand-iphone2').delay(200).animate({opacity: '1', bottom: '0px', left:'50px'},500);                  
$('#hand2-iphone2').delay(2000).animate({opacity: '1'},0);
$('.roundabout-holder').animate({opacity: '1'},500);
$('#boni-text').animate({opacity: '1'},500);
```

Comment: Any errors reported in the developer tools' JavaScript console?

Comment: Try passing a number instead of a string as in `.css('opacity', 0)`

Comment: Try using single quotes.  What is the rendered markup in Safari?  And what version of Safari/

Comment: Are you able to use `$('#iframe-youtube').css("display", "none");` instead?

Comment: does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/k46Vk/

Comment: @DavidThomas I am using windows, I couldnt find any javascript console for Safari and tried to get as extension, could not connect to server (?)

Comment: @elclanrs I have tried, not working

Comment: @user1721691: Have a read of [Safari's Developer Tools Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html). It will, probably, be helpful.

Comment: Try on MacOS, it could be some Windows issue with Safari. Apple does not support the Win version anymore AFAIK, and nobody uses Safari on Windows anyway.

Comment: I have tried everything you offered but no way, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `?wmode=opaque` to the end of your youtube link in the iframe.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="iframe-youtube">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bZqnqH9s1jk?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#iframe-youtube').css("opacity", 0);​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gpGMZ/2/)**

**Light reading**

- [overlay opaque div over youtube iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)
- [Youtube video inside iframe not hiding in Safari 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700577/youtube-video-inside-iframe-not-hiding-in-safari-5-1)