# Safari browser not processing JQuery Right but works in IE|Chrome|FireFox Just fine

Tags: jquery, html, safari, cross-browser

I am working on a page for my brother. I am using mainly just Jquery and HTML to build it.

The problem that I am running into is that the page loads fine in IE Chrome and FireFox but when you load it in Safari it blows up. You cant go to the reels link without it all coming apart. When you click on reals it SHOULD expand the 4 videos. Then when you click on another button it should close those and move on. However it just leaves them open. This is ONLY in Safari Mind you.

Here is the link
http://anthonyrussell.info/test/jbp/index.html

And here is my source

```
<!--This site is an RT Applications Inc. Production (http://www.AnthonyRussell.info) -->
<!--None of the content on this site is in the public domain. Anything that is taken from this site must first be approaved by the sites owner-->
<!--http://www.JaysonBernard.com Is owned by JaysonBernard and maintained by RT Applications Inc.-->

<html> 
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!--  for running live--> 
     <!--  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  <!--for running local-->
       <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){       
            $("#WelcomeTable").hide();
            $("#Count").show();
            $("#Count").text("5").delay(500).fadeOut(1000,function(){
                $("#Count").text("4").show().delay(500).fadeOut(1000,function(){
                    $("#Count").text("3").show().delay(500).fadeOut(1000,function(){
                        $("#Count").text("2").show().delay(500).fadeOut(1000,function(){
                            $("#Count").text("1").show().delay(500).fadeOut(1000, function(){                               
                                $("#WelcomeTable").fadeIn(500,function(){
                                    $("#WelcomeImage").fadeIn(500);
                                    $("#Title").fadeIn(500,function(){
                                        $("#HomeBt").fadeIn(500,function(){
                                            $("#ReelBt").fadeIn(500,function(){
                                                $("#ResumeBt").fadeIn(500,function(){
                                                    $("#PhotosBt").fadeIn(500,function(){
                                                        $("#ContactBt").fadeIn(500);
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });                                 
                                });
                            }); 
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            $("#HomeBt").click(function(){
                $("#video").hide();
                $(".content").hide();
                $("#WelcomeImage").slideDown(200);
            });
            $("#ReelBt").click(function(){
                $("#video").hide();
                $(".content").hide();
                $("#WelcomeImage").slideUp(200, function(){
                    $("#ReelPage").slideDown(1000);
                });
            });
            $("#ResumeBt").click(function(){
                $("#video").hide();
                $(".content").hide();
                $("#WelcomeImage").slideUp(200, function(){
                    $("#ResumePage").slideDown(1000);
                });
            });
            $("#PhotosBt").click(function(){
                $("#video").hide();
                $(".content").hide();
                $("#WelcomeImage").slideUp(200, function(){
                    $("#PhotosPage").slideDown(1000);
                });
            });
            $("#ContactBt").click(function(){
                $("#video").hide();
                $(".content").hide();
                $("#WelcomeImage").slideUp(200, function(){
                    $("#ContactPage").slideDown(1000);
                });
            });
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                alert("I Told you not to click me bitch!");
            });
            $("#img1").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img1").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img1").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img1").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img2").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img2").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img2").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img2").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img3").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img3").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img3").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img3").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img4").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img4").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img4").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img4").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img5").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img5").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img5").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img5").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img6").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img6").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img6").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img6").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img7").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img7").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img7").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img7").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img8").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img8").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img8").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img8").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img9").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img9").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img9").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img9").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img10").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img10").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img10").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img10").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img11").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img11").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img11").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img11").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img12").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img12").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img12").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img12").css("width","200");
            });
            $("#img13").mouseover(function(){
                $("#img13").css("width","400");
            });
            $("#img13").mouseout(function(){
                $("#img13").css("width","200");
            });
        });
       </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <!--Buttons and Landing page logic-->
        <center>
            <table border=0 id="WelcomeTable" style="display:none; float:center;">

                    <td width=350>
                        <!--<p id="Title" style="display:none; font-size:70; line-height:55%; margin:2%">Jayson Bernard</p>-->
                        <img id="Title" style="display:none; margin:2%" src="images/jbLogo.png"/>
                        <br>
                        <table border=0>
                            <td width=350 height=50>                                                    
                                <button id="HomeBt" style="height:50; width:60; display:none;">Home</button>
                                <button id="ReelBt" style="height:50; width:60; display:none;">Reel</button>
                                <button id="ResumeBt" style="height:50; width:70; display:none;">Resume</button>
                                <button id="PhotosBt" style="height:50; width:60; display:none;">Photos</button>
                                <button id="ContactBt" style="height:50; width:70; display:none;">Contact</button>                  
                            </td>
                        </table>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <img style="display:none; line-height:70%;" id="WelcomeImage" src="images/landingPageImg.png" height=800 >
                    </td>

            </table>
            <p id="Count" style="font-size:150; margin:10% 45%; display:none;"></p>     
        </center>       
        <!--END-->


        <!--BEGINING-->
        <center>
            <table style="display:none;" id="ReelPage" class="content">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1>Reel</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>                
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Hgc0FBJEZr4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>         
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZfsoW2YY9o8?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uJO5O78qx54?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>                     
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gr0zfqVa0CM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
        <!--END-->

        <!--BEGINING-->
        <center>
            <table style="display:none;" id="ResumePage" class="content">
                <td width=600>
                    <h1>Resume</h1>
                    <p>Hair: Brown<br/>
Eyes: Blue<br/>
Height: 6'1"<br/>
Weight: 190 lbs<br/>
<br/>
FILM CHARACTER DIRECTOR<br/>
"The Landlord" "QVC Host" By: Emile Hyde<br/>
" D.I.N.K.'s" " Charles" By: Robert Alaniz<br/>
" An Unfortunate Idea" "The Clown" By: Nick Scala<br/>
" ILL WILL" "Chris" By: T.A. Jones<br/>
" XYRESIN" "Luke" By: Rice Omary<br/>
<br/>
TELEVISION<br/>
"Taking the Lunge" Reality show (me) Pesent<br/>
" Chicago Fire" "First basemen" 2012<br/>
"Underemployed" "Protective Father" 2011<br/>
"Turks" "Leather clad guy" 1999<br/>
"ER" "School teacher" 1998<br/>
<br/>
COMMERCIALS<br/>
"Green Landscaping" " Satisfied customer" 2011<br/>
" The Civil Rights Agenda" "Spokesman" 2011<br/>
<br/>
TRAINING<br/>
Act One Studio Scene Study/ Advanced O'Brian<br/>
Second City Classes A-D & Writing Upon Request<br/>
Marybeth Liss (Red Twist) Acting Coach/Vocal trainer Marybeth Liss<br/>
<br/>
SPECIAL SKILLS<br/>
Stand up Comedian and Writer.<br/>
Improv Skills and Comedic Timing.<br/>
Training in Judo.<br/>
Broad sword trained.</p>
                </td>
            </table>
        <center>
        <!--END-->

        <!--BEGINING-->
        <table style="display:none;" id="PhotosPage" class="content">
            <td width=600>
                <h1>Photos</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img id="img3" src="photos/3.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img4" src="photos/4.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img1" src="photos/1.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img2" src="photos/2.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img7" src="photos/7.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img10" src="photos/10.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img11" src="photos/11.jpg" width="200"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img id="img5" src="photos/5.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img6" src="photos/6.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img8" src="photos/8.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img9" src="photos/9.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img12" src="photos/12.jpg" width="200"/>
                            <img id="img13" src="photos/13.jpg" width="200"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                                       
                </table>
            </td>
        </table>
        <!--END-->

        <!--BEGINING-->

        <center>

            <table style="display:none;" id="ContactPage" class="content">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1>Contact</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/MrJayBernard" data-widget-id="319617825352323072">Tweets by @MrJayBernard</a>
                        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3981346/" target=_blank border="0"><img src="images/imdblogo.jpg" width=100 height=100 border="0"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jayson.bernard1" target=_blank border="0"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png" width=100 height=100 border="0"/></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>            
                        <form >
                            Send me a message!
                            <br/>
                            <textarea cols=30 rows=1>Subject</textarea>
                            <br/>
                            <textarea cols=30 rows=10>Content</textarea>
                            <br/>
                            <button id="submit" style="width:265;">Send</button>
                        </form> 
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            </table>
        </center>
        <!--END-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Any insight at all would be aprreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me in Safari 5.1.7 on Windows

Comment: Your jquery seems to be looking for an element with the ID of `video` but I don't see anything in your markup with that ID. FYI, you can do a lot to optimize this jQuery.

Comment: @DA. Yeah I had marked the videos with ID video in some debuging trying to resolve this issue and forgot to take that out. Also I know it needs SERIOUS optimizing. I just started jQuery last week so I am learning haha. Feel free to point out anything that can use an update in an answer and Ill upvote.

Comment: @winterblood I am also using 5.1.7 on Windows. I wonder if this is local to windows 8 then

Comment: @AMR I am on Win7, so there is the possibility.

Comment: @winterblood I guess testing across 4 desktop browsers and a mobile browser isn't enough these days. Guess I'll be booting up virtualbox...

Comment: @AMR Have a look at http://browserstack.com

Comment: @JonathanSampson SO AWESOME FIND! Turns out that on their it fails on Windows 7 and Windows 8 with Safari 5.1 Still no clue why but that is a VERY small percentage of people using those so I have some time to figure that out. Works like a charm across all other browsers and OS's. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would work to reduce the complexity of your code. Think of it in parts - you have a part that counts down a timer, a part that hides the timer and reveals the buttons, and maybe even a part that controls the delay at which each button is revealed.

By reducing the complexity, and improving the readability, you can more easily troubleshoot your code in various browsers and environments. As for the iframe's not hiding along with their container, [this seems to have been asked once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700577/youtube-video-inside-iframe-not-hiding-in-safari-5-1).

Consider the following, viewable on http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/9B39g/:

```
// Important references
var countdn = $("#countdown"),
    buttons = $("#buttons a"),
    seconds = 5;

// Interval to handle the countdown
var cInterval = setInterval(function () {
    countdn.fadeOut(250, reduceNum);
}, 1000);

// Logic responsible for the countdown
function reduceNum () {
    if ( --seconds ) {
        $(this).text(seconds).fadeIn(250);
    } else {
        clearInterval(cInterval);
        transitionLayout();
    }
}

// Logic to reveal our buttons when the time is right
function revealButtons () {
    buttons.each(function (index) {
        $(this).delay(index * 500).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
    });
}

// Logic to handle the transition
function transitionLayout () {
    countdn.remove();
    revealButtons();
}
```

Comment: I see that it works and the code makes sense except how its initiated. How does it know to start the counter? I know that in my code I have the $(document).ready function that tells it to start when the doc is done loading. Will code execute even without this?

Comment: @AMR The `setInterval` portion starts immediately. You could place that within `document.ready` if you like though.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I missed the reduceNum function call that was in that. Wow very nicely done.

Comment: @AMR If this solves your problem, please consider accepting to close the loop on this question.

Comment: Well the problem isn't the buttons or the count down. The problem is in Safari 5.1 on Windows 7 and 8 the Reels Window does not close out.

Comment: @AMR Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700577/youtube-video-inside-iframe-not-hiding-in-safari-5-1